# RoR variable doesn't hold associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

New to RoR, here couldn't find the solution I was looking for so I'm typing my problem here:

I have a web app where after the user is logged in they will be redirected to a dashboard that shows them their various information.

For now - as I'm getting the feel of RoR - the view of the dashboard was suppose to get a lot of information:

```
 def index
    @logged_user = Person.includes(:user, :addresses).find(session[:user_id])
 end
```

but when I checked using @logged_user.inspect it only gave me this

```
   #<Person (person model attributes here) >
```

I checked the log and it seems the User and Addresses were loaded

[printscreen of my log http://prntscr.com/c40fee](http://prntscr.com/c40fee)

but they aren't in the @logged_user variable... did I miss a step here? where did I go wrong?

EDIT:

here's the model of Person

```
 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

   has_one :user, :dependent => :destroy 
   has_one :medical_record
   has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :contacts,:dependent => :destroy
   has_many :enrollments_as_student, :class_name => 'Enrollment', :foreign_key => :student_id, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy: true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :medical_record, allow_destroy: true
 end
```

model for User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :username, :password, format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ñÑ]+\Z/, message: "Special characters aren't allowed"}
  validates :username, uniqueness: {message: "username is already taken"}

  has_secure_password

  belongs_to :person
```

end

model for Addresses

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :street, :barangay, :city, :province,
    presence: {message: "Fill in all necessary fields"}
  validates :zipcode,
    numericality: {message: "Zipcodes should only contain numbers"},
    length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 4, message: "Invalid zipcode length"}

  belongs_to :person
end
```

also snippet for the login

```
def login

  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:receptions][:username])

  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:receptions][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.person_id
      flash[:notice] = "You have succfully logged in"
      redirect_to '/dashboards'
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid username or password"
      redirect_to '/login'
end
```

Comment: can you post your model structure? And are you using `devise`?

Comment: `session[:user_id]` seems to be containing user's id, not person's. Thus I guess you should be writing `User.find(session[:user_id])`

Comment: I'm not using devise. I will add my model later.

while it does say session[:user_id] it doesn't actually hold the user_id here I'll also add code for login.